# Serving a static react application behind a Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, create-react-app, kubernetes-ingress

I'm currently trying to setup a react SPA as a deployment/service on kubernetes. Like the backend services I have running currently, I want to be able to hit it behind an Ingress.

Because the SPA is just a bunch of static files, I'm exposing the files through nginx. The container that runs in the deployment has nginx installed to serve the static assets (`nginx -g  daemon off` in the docker file). This works completely fine if I expose the deployment with a `LoadBalancer`, but if I use an Ingress, I get no response. Are there any special things to consider when serving static assets behind an ingress? Or any known references/resources for doing this?

Here's my ingress.yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: web-static-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: web-backend-service
            servicePort: 80
  - host: app.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: web-frontend-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Can you share your `ingress.yaml`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jay-khatri/cde5ab10bdfbaa1a6c5f52943e215181

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to have an ingress controller deployed on your cluster for an ingress resource to actually take effect**. Here is the [installation guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) of Nginx ingress controller.An example ingress to serve static content would look like below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: web-backend-service
            servicePort: 80
  - host: app.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: web-frontend-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Here is a [guide](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/09/05/kraken-kubernetes-ingress-nginx-frontend/) on how to serve angular 8 application on Minikube using Nginx ingress.

Comment: is `class: "nginx"` a requirement? Are the annotations that I'm currently referencing not working because I'm not using it? Here's my ingress.yml: https://gist.github.com/jay-khatri/cde5ab10bdfbaa1a6c5f52943e215181

Comment: if you have multiple ingress controllers then nginx is required because based on that annotation nginx ingress controller will kick in

Comment: Also you need to install nginx ingress controller on your cluster..just having ingress kind resource without a controller will not work